Metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ Without Guaranteed Equilateral Triangles
Is there a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (i.e. a function $\mu:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ such that $\mu(x,y)= \mu(y,x)$, $\mu(x,y)=0\implies x=y$, and $\mu(x,y)+\mu(y,z)\geq \mu(x,z)$) where for any points $x$, $y$, we cannot necessarily find a third point $z$ such that $\mu(x,y)=\mu(y,z)=\mu(z,x)$?
Obviously in $\mathbb R$ the regular distance function works, since there are no equilateral triangles anywhere. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, it guarantees no set of four points works, but is it possible to find $\textit{some}$ metric where you weren't always guaranteed triangles?

Just any metric? Not for example, "a metric inducing the Euclidean topology"? If not, your observation that there's such a metric on $\Bbb R$ provides a straightforward answer, since there is a bijection $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$. You can transport the usual metric along this bijection - ie define $\mu(x, y) = |f(x) - f(y)|$.

I'm not sure that that works, since it's not clear to me that any of those bijections would preserve the triangle inequality

@WilliamGrannis What do you mean by “preserving triangle inequality”? It’s literally a bijection. In a sense you’re just renaming your points. Of course the triangle inequality will hold.

The triangle inequality for this $\mu$ is the statement "for any $x, y, z$, we have $|f(x) - f(z)| \le |f(x) - f(y)| + |f(y) - f(z)|$". This is true, simply because the triangle inequality is true for the usual metric on $\Bbb R$.
